# CI_Template' not found

Tags: codeigniter, model-view-controller

I want to load model using

```
$this->load->model('apotek_data');

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('apotek_data');
    $this->template->write_view('sidenavs', 'template/default_sidenavs', true);
    $this->template->write_view('navs', 'template/default_topnavs.php', true);
    $this->load->database();
}
```

But when I put it `($this->load->model)` in my code, the view doesn't show, and display an error message.

> Fatal error: Class 'CI_Template' not found in
>   D:\wamp64\www\apotek\system\core\Common.php on line 196

What should I do?

Comment: What template library are you using? `write_view` isn't CI native

Comment: have you loaded the library template in autoload or controller?

Comment: @Alex I use the one in https://www.roytuts.com tutorial.

Comment: @pradeep yes, I've already done that, but still error

Comment: I'm trying to help you, don't make me have to search a website to find the exact thing you are using. Direct link please.

Comment: The fact that your error says CI_Template is troubling as it should just be Template as I've said in my answer comments.

Comment: @Alex I'm sorry. This is the link for template library https://github.com/ajhoel43/ci-with-gentelella/blob/master/application/libraries/Template.php. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Load  the template library:

`$this->load->library('template');`

OR:

In `config/autoload.php` add `template` in the libraries array.

I don't know the name of your library so I am assuming it is `template` if it is not - change it with the name of the library.

Comment: Yes, the name is template. I've added template in autoload.php libraries array. I also tried $this->load->library('template');. But it still displays an error

Comment: If you are using a 3rd party library then make sure it is in the library folder. If not please provide more details on the library you are using (a link) as an edit to your question. Not everyone is familiar with all the CI libraries available.

Comment: I should also note that the name and declaration are important `Template.php` and `class Template` note capitals.

Answer (score 0):

For any other person experiencing a 'CI_Template not found' error:

In my case, I was loading a library (in the constructor) with the same name as the controller that was being accessed.

```
class Authld extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('Authld');
    }
}
```

I had to change the name of the controller for the issue to be resolved.

```
class Authentication extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->library('Authld');
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Your Template.php maybe looks like this:

```
class Template extends MX_Controller{
```

If so, change the MX to CI (CI_Controller).